# Performing ajax request in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, oop

I am trying to perform ajax request in my plugin. What I have done is:

```
    Class Someclass {

        public function __construct(){

        }

        public function current_page_function(){

            add_action(
                "wp_ajax_test_ajax",array($this,'test_ajax')
            );

            $this->data=array();

            View_Includer::load('index',$this->data,false,false,false,false,true,false,false);
        }

         public function test_ajax(){
            wp_send_json_success('Science achieved!');
            exit();
        }
```

}

Script:

```
    var send_ajax_request = function( cpt_id ) {

        // Define the function and the data to send to the server.
        var data = {
            'action':    'test_ajax',
            'post_type': cpt_id
        };

        // Send the request to the server and handle the response.
        jQuery.post( Essestials.ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
            return response;
            // Handle your response here.
        });

    };
```

When I do this, the wordpress return 400 error code. But when I do as below:

```
    Class Someclass {

        public function __construct(){
            add_action(
                "wp_ajax_test_ajax",array($this,'test_ajax')
            );
        }

        public function current_page_function(){
            $this->data=array();
            View_Includer::load('index',$this->data,false,false,false,false,true,false,false);
        }

         public function test_ajax(){
            wp_send_json_success('Science achieved!');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

it returns the following response :

```
    {success: true, data: "Science achieved!"}
```

what wrong am I doing on the first process ? Why it works only when I add the hook in constructor ?
Any kind of helps are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some actions must be registered as early as possible. When you put it in the  `"current_page_function"` method, (depending on your program) it might be too late.

Hence, the `wp_ajax_*` hook cannot find your action, and it returns the error.

Comment: is it simply the reason ? I mean ajax request is proceeded only when action is registered and page is fully loaded. By that time , wp_ajax_* should have find the hook. Can you please make it more clear ? Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the full code I cannot confirm it 100%. Yes, your ajax request is called when the page is loaded. But, every time you call ajax function, WordPress doing it's program-cycle again (bootstrapping, registering hooks, init, instantiating classes, etc) to return a response. Because that's how web works.